# A typecast to void? or what? and why?

Tags: c++

I was looking llvm clang's implementation of the C++ standard library...
In file `mutex.cpp` I found the following code:

```
void
mutex::unlock() _NOEXCEPT
{
    int ec = pthread_mutex_unlock(&__m_);
    (void)ec;                              // What??, Why??? O.o
    assert(ec == 0);
}
```

I don't understand what that expression is doing and why...
I need some explanation.

Comment: Probably to avoid compiler warning about unused variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this expression is used that to avoid a compiler warning that the variable was declared but was not used.

As **user2864740** pointed out the assert statement in this code can be a mcaro that in some conditions does not use the variable. That is it can be expanded to an empty statement.

Comment: +1 I confirm it too, I use it all the time to silent the compiler.